# How to modulate the amplitude of a square wave at high speed (MHz)?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, signal-processing, dac, dsp

I want to build a modulator for driving a laser. I want the laser to produce square pulses with varying amplitudes. Hence I built a 1 MHz square wave oscillator (relaxation oscillator with an opamp.) **How can I set the amplitude of each of the square pulses?** I later want to create more channels to drive more lasers in parallel.

My initial idea was to use analog opamp buffers to make parallel copies of the 1Mhz square wave into as many channels as I want. By controlling the gain of the buffer amplifiers digitally I will be able to set the amplitude of the outcoming square pulses. If I use a digital potentiometer to tune the gain I should be able to do this.

How can I do it quickly, for example, at 1MHz? If I use a digital potentiometer with an SPI interface, will I be able to change it quickly enough with an Arduino?

Then again adding more SPI slaves for different channels might reduce the rate at which I can set the digital potentiometers. How can I do this? Will a faster microcontroller do the trick? Are there any other options?

I have no experience in FPGA programming so that approach is only being considered in the worst case. If that's the only option I might try to build a logic using Icestudio, but a simpler solution is preferred.

Edit: I need 4bits of resolution (16 level pulse amplitude modulation.)

Comment: Perhaps you can define the interface signal spec range in useful terms for driving  laser instead of worrying about implementation. This requires the datasheet for lasing and user interface.

Comment: Use an analog comparator not an op-amp for your oscillator. Use a DAC output as VCC for the comparator. You may need to buffer the DAC output with another op-amp. This is a classic way to achieve amplitude modulation.

Comment: @mkeith This is exactly my idea. But what kind of DAC can do this purpose? How to generate an arbitary signal quick enough to vary the amplitude of each square pulse coming from the oscillator?

Comment: Do you want to be able to set a different amplitude for each pulse in the square wave?

Comment: @bobflux Yes. That is what I want

Comment: That requires updating the DAC at 1Msps or 500ksps at least if its output is gated. How many channels do you want?

Comment: @bobflux I would ultimately like 16 channels but 8 would do as a starting point

Comment: So, you'll need 8 or 16 6-bit DACs. Most MCUs don't have that much direct IO. At 1 MHz that's also a data rate of 100 Mbps. You'll need an FPGA. Where is the modulation data coming from ?

Comment: I dont need this to be in realtime, I could load up the modulation data from a computer into some sort of memory and then push it the laser. FPGA is not an option for me at the moment. @jp314

Comment: Maybe DMA directly to IO could do it. Look at the techniques here: https://github.com/wramsdell/TriantaduoWS2811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from our chat in the comments, you need to generate 1MHz "square waves" with independent control over the amplitude of each pulse, with 8-16 channels, and 4 bits amplitude per channel.

I assume you want all the channels synchronized.

Option 1: gated DACs.

Each channel has a 4 bit DAC, followed by an analog SPDT switch that can either output the DAC analog value, or zero volts. Thus, while the switches are off, the DACs can be updated in any order. Then you wait for them to settle, and flip all the switches at the same time, outputting a pulse of the required voltage on each channel. To end the pulses, just flip the switches back to zero. In this case, the 1MHz square wave controls the switches.

Option 2: Arbitrary Waveform Generator

That's basically what you are doing, after all. In this case, the DACs need to be able to store a code word in a register, then load it into the DAC output register on a pulse on a LDAC input pin. This is common on DAC chips. So, you load all the values in all the DACs, and pulse LDAC so they all output their codes at the same time. In this case, there are no switches, and to return to zero volt output, you simply load a zero value in all the DACs.

The only difference between the two is that the first option requires 1M updates per second but needs more hardware, while the second requires 2M updates per second and needs less hardware.

Note a 4-bit DAC can be implemented with a quad flop logic chip and a bunch of resistors, for example in R2R. An octal flop can do two 4-bit DACs. These also have a RESET input, so that may be useful to return to 0V without loading zeros into all the registers, so:

Option 3:

Each DAC uses two 4-bit flops, one to register the data from a bus that feeds all DACs, and keeps it until the other 4-bit flop outputs it onto the resistors on the synchronization pulse. So, basically, one 74HC573 and 4 resistors per channel, which is about 50 cents.

Option 4:

FPGA or CPLD with the same logic inside, and resistors tied to the pins.

[image]

Basically, present a data word on b0-b7, then pulse l1 or l2 to load it in the corresponding flop. Once both are loaded, pulse LDAC to push all the data words to the output flops, and let the resistors do the conversion to analog. This one uses a 8-bit bus, so two channels are loaded on each step.

I didn't bother to look for a 4-bit flop, but it would be possible to do it with a 4-bit bus and 4-bit flops too:

[image]

Logistics:

Since you need 1-2 updates per channel at a 1MHz rate, that's 16-32M 4-bit words per second, or 64-128 Mbits/s. This means SPI and I2C are definitely out.

If you use the 4-bit bus above, you could use a quad SPI output on a micro to output all the words. You'll need a counter to address each flop so they all load their proper data word, something like a 74HC4017. But you still need to initiate about 1M SPI transfers per second, so you need a very fast micro and accurate timings.

You could also use GPIO, with the 8 bit bus, just output a byte with 2 DAC values on an 8 bit port, and use other GPIOs to control the loading into the flops. A 4-bit to 16-bit decoder can be used to generate the loading pulses. You'll need a MCU with fast enough GPIOs, of course.

Another option would be to just steamroll over the whole thing and use a USB FIFO chip. These will take a bulk USB transfer and output it on 8 parallel pins, so you got your 8 bit data bus. To load the data into the appropriate registers, you can use a ripple counter driven by the same clock. That's quite a simple option, and it allows for unlimited data length too.

And of course, there's the FPGA, which would be much more compact.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I understood this correctly, this is exactly what I wanted. I totally agree with the logic circuit. However, I doubt that the R2R DAC might limit the speed. In any case, since I have a parallel interface before the dac, I think I can get a ready-made IC capable of fast conversion. With that said, my question is about the USB FIFO chip. What is it exactly? I could not find a clear explanation of it online.

Comment: Is the FIFO chip a device that takes a bulk of data into some kind of buffer in it and passes it onto the 8 bit pins at a high rate? I saw some of theses chips say upto 10 Mbyte/sec. As far as I understand they also supply a clock signal.

Comment: R2R will not limit the speed unless the resistors are too high value and the input capacitance of whatever comes next forms a RC lowpass. For the USB FIFO, you can try something in the FT232 family from FTDI. I've never used these chips, so I can't give detailed advice. I used Cypress FX2, which has a similar interface. Basically, you give it a read clock, and it outputs a byte on every clock, as long as the PC pushes data on the other end. You can do whatever you want with this byte.

Comment: Awesome! I am going to try my best to realize this circuit! Many thanks

Comment: Cypress FX2 is a USB FIFO chip with an embedded 8052 micro. It's not difficult to program. I got the full USB bandwidth, 48 megabytes per second, using a python script with python-libusb, but it was 10 years ago, so please don't ask for details. I think some FTDI chips can reach that bandwidth also. They don't have a micro inside, so that may be simpler. Basically, it's a FIFO, so it has a "read clock" pin, and when you pulse it, it spits out a byte. Whatever controls that clock controls the rate at which data comes out, that's the point of a FIFO.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't described what modulation accuracy, or how many steps (bits) you might need.

If only a few steps, then this will work and be reasonably efficient:
[image: Laser driver]

Choose VDD to be 1-2 V above the laser diode VF. Make VDD your fixed amplitude square wave. Bias the NPN's base at about 1.5 V (higher makes the system less temperature sensitive). With a MCU, switch small FETs to change the NPN's current (each R will add a current of (VB-0.7)/R to the output.

If you want more resolution, use a DAC (or arbitrary waveform generator to drive the base go the NPN instead (with a fixed R from emitter to GND).

Comment: I would at least like a 4 bit resolution and  would mean I need 4 gpios being switched at a MHz rate (how to do this?!). However, I also am looking for a design that’s scalable to multiple channels. I think the parallel interface will create a shortage of GPIO pins

Comment: oh nice, a self-buiilt parallel-input IDAC solution!

Comment: @RaviPradip use an R/2R arrangement: resistor currents add in parallel. 4 bits is 6% between levels so you don't have to worry about laser trimmed resistors. That gets you down to the info-entropy number of bits of GPIO.

Comment: @Dannie Sure. This is a possible strategy. But how to feed the R/2R DAC with fast enough digital data aka how to switch the input bits fast enough? It should be possible with an FPGA but can i do it with a microcontroller?

Comment: @RaviPradip If you have a microcontroller which can generate anything useful at 1MHz (which you will need to generate the stream anyway) it's unlikely to have problems driving GPIOs at that speed. Obviously, if your microcontroller is running with a 1MHz clock then it won't be much use,because you can't even generate a value at that speed: GPIO speed is unlikely to be a limiting factor.

Answer (score 1):

1 MHz isn't "quick" by modern microcontroller / logic standards.

Your system's a bit awkward: the "easy" part is the generation of the square wave, the hard part is the amplitude modulation. Anything able to do the latter can inherently do the former. So: The square-wave generator is superfluous if you have the amplitude modulator...

Don't use adjustable resistors to adjust the gain, just use a computer and DACs (typically, current DACs, so-called IDACs) to generate your waveforms.

There's many *Real-Time OS* (RTOS) choices for microcontrollers which would allow you to set up things in a finely-controllable timing. Arduino is definitely not one of them. Other than that, a higher-end microcontroller (either with a DAC built in, or with a parallel bus that allows control of an external DAC) should be able to do what you want, although if you're experimenting, a PC-style computer connected to a DAQ system, or an SDR transmitter, might be the more flexible thing.

When you look at actual high-speed communications, where the intensity of light is modulated at multiple GHz, you'll find you cannot modulate the intensity of a laser diode fast enough for these high speeds. There, you use a DAC to control a Mach-Zehnder Modulator (MZM) instead to modulate the amplitude of your transmission.

For your benign speeds, you can safe yourself trouble of building a laser diode driver, amplifiers, etc, by using a SFP fiberoptical module (these can be gotten used e.g. from ebay very cheap, or even new they aren't expensive). To connect to that, [the osmocom sfp-experimenter](https://osmocom.org/projects/misc-hardware/wiki/Sfp-experimenter) might be a nice design:

[image: SFP-Experimenter]
<sup>Osmocom sfp-experimenter: an experimentation board to use cheap SFP modules. [Link](https://osmocom.org/projects/misc-hardware/wiki/Sfp-experimenter). Might be commercially available through the sysmocom webshop.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! First of all, I understand the modulation technique using M-Z interferometers. However, this specific laser of mine is on-chip and is capable of responding to direct current modulations over a MHz.  With that said, What do you mean by a higher end microcontroller? I looked into a few but I am having difficulty finding with a fast enough interface. RTOS is also something new to me...I will look it up. Further I do have an a cheap RTL-SDR device, I need to figure out if it is possible to use it as a DAC.

Comment: 10 Gbps direct laser modulation is possible. But it only works for short fiber links because the laser "chirps" when it is modulated, so the resulting pulses will spread out due to dispersion in a fiber.

Comment: Exactly it’s an on chip device and the link is very short.

Comment: RTL-SDRs do not contain a DAC, so they're useless for this.

Comment: Many dont, like the one i have. However, SDR devices like PlutoSDR and HackRF have transmit capabilities, which includes a DAC. @MarcusMüller

Comment: @RaviPradip RTL-SDR is a specific device type, based on the RTL2832U chip; these are all receivers only (they are terrestrial TV receiver USB dongles with a direct IQ sampling mode). A PlutoSDR and a HackRF are not RTL-SDRs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oops! Got it.